# Bash - Delete lines not ending with a number

Tags: linux, bash

I need to remove all lines (in text file) not ending with a number.

Before:

```
 Frog
 Toad 8
 Snake 3
 Spider
```

After:

```
 Toad 8
 Snake 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed to edit "in place":

```
sed -i '/[^0-9]$/d' file
```

Comment: If you use `-i.bak` this will also work on BSD's and Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `grep` is a perfect candidate:

```
bash-4.3$ cat test 
 Frog
 Toad 8
 Snake 3
 Spider
bash-4.3$ grep [0-9]$ test 
 Toad 8
 Snake 3
```